# How to find the service principal assigned to a newly created AKS cluster?

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I have just created an AKS cluster using a standard `az aks create ... --ssh-key-value ...`.
According to https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-service-principal,

> an AKS cluster is created, and because an existing service principal is not specified, a service principal is created for the cluster.

Where can I find the created SP?
Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As [Bruno Faria](https://serverfault.com/users/218644/bruno-faria) said, you can find the service principal in Azure Active Directory, `Azure Active Directory -> App registrations -> All apps`
like this:

[image]

Also you can use `az aks list --resource-group <your-resouece-group>` to find your service principal:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is what we were looking for. How to get the SP assigned to a specific cluster, which is especially relevant if you have several clusters and several non-AKS specific SPs. Thanx

Answer (score 4):

Go to Azure Active Directory >> App Registrations >> Select All Apps from the dropdown menu >> find your app and click on it.

The service principal will be the application Id and the secret will be the key under settings.

Comment: I went there, and there are several apps, none of them with the name of the created cluster.
What I was looking to understand is how do I know which of these has been assigned to the newly created cluster. Thx

Comment: Well, I just noticed that `~/.azure/acsServicePrincipal.json` has `service_principal`with the same value as one of the apps' `ApplicationID`. Curiously, in the portal, this app has a link to `Create Service Principal`. Is this ok? Thx

Answer (score 2):

The output from "az aks list" should contain your service principal clientId.

Comment: How does this differ from the accepted answer by @Jason Ye ?

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
az aks list --resource-group core-project --query="[0].servicePrincipalProfile.clientId"
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link for step by step guide for app registration in Azure AD - https://sanganakauthority.blogspot.com/2019/04/how-to-create-service-principal-or-app.html